# count items using nested loops

Tags: python, nested-loops

```
def count_vowel_phonemes(phonemes):
    """ (list of list of str) -> int

    Return the number of vowel phonemes in phonemes.

    >>> phonemes = [['N', 'OW1'], ['Y', 'EH1', 'S']]
    >>> count_vowel_phonemes(phonemes)
    2
    """
    number_of_vowel_phonemes = 0
    for phoneme in phonemes:
        for item in phoneme:
            if 0 or 1 or 2 in item:
                number_of_vowel_phonemes = number_of_vowel_phonemes + 1
    return number_of_vowel_phonemes
```

**Description**:
A vowel phoneme is a phoneme whose last character is 0, 1, or 2. As examples, the word BEFORE (B IH0 F AO1 R) contains two vowel phonemes and the word GAP (G AE1 P) has one.

The parameter represents a list of list of phonemes. The function is to return the number of vowel phonemes found in the list of list of phonemes.
Basically this question asks me to count the number of digits in this list, but my codes keep returning 0 which is strange. Is there something wrong with my code? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

```
if any(i in item for i in ("0", "1","2"):
```

Your code would actually return `5` for your test input  as `or 1` will always evaluate to `True`, you are checking `bool(1)` not actually checking if `1` is in `item` and you are also comparing `ints` to `strings`.

You could reduce your code to a generator expression with `sum` and using `str.endswith` to find subelements ending in 0,1 or 2:

```
return sum(item.endswith(("0","1","2")) for phoneme in phonemes for item in phoneme)
```

which outputs:

```
In [4]: phonemes = [['N', 'OW1'], ['Y', 'EH1', 'S']]
In [5]: count_vowel_phonemes(phonemes)
Out[5]: 2
```

The correct method to test using `or` would be:

```
if "0" in item or "1" in item or "2" in item:
```

which is equivalent to the `any` line.

Comment: Thanks!!It passed all my examples after I changed my if statement.

Comment: @Carlos, no worries, you're welcome, I would recommend the str.endswith example.